# How to use Mockito to verify a method is called in another method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a class A with a publish() method. In the method will call another method and pass the class A object as a parameter to Class B.

```
public class A {
    public void publish() {
      ClassB classb = new ClassB();
      classb.sendRequest(this)
    }
}
```

The question is how to use Mockito to verify the `sendRequest` method is called when the publish() method is called? I am new to Mockito.

Comment: first link on google https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-verify

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use Mockito if you create a new ClassB instance in your method.
You should refactor publish() to take ClassB as a parameter, and then you can send your Mockito mock instead of a real ClassB, and verify on it.

Like so:

```
public class A {

    public void publish(ClassB classb){
        classb.sendRequest(this)
    }
 }
```

And in your test:

```
ClassB mockClassB = mock(ClassB.class);
A a = new A();
a.publish(mockClassB);

verify(mockClassB, times(1)).sendRequest(any());
```

Comment: So how to test classb.sendRequest(this)  is called when classa.publish() is called without taking Class B as a parameter?

Comment: You can't. You have to refactor. You could also add a ClassB member field, and use a setter to set the mock. But some refactoring is mandatory.

Comment: @HenlenLee OT: Since the only thing that call `A`s `publish` method does is calling a method on its parameter passing itself along the question arises: Why does it need to be in class `A`? could't the caller of `a.publish(b);` call `b.sendRequest(a);` directly? That would remove the dependency of class `A` to class `B` completely...